# Does Hinduism have a heaven and hell of the Abrahamic kind?

Tags: philosophy

In Abrahamic faiths, heaven and hell are physical destinations after one dies. In Hindu philosophy- there do seem to be heaven and hell- but also reincarnation. How are these two made compatible?

Comment: People in Hells and Heavens are for limited time frame, it works that way, after it they are borne in some other realms based on their Karma!

Comment: Abhrahmic Religions have linear time based theology and thus have a definite starting and ending point. The end defines who gets hell or heaven for eternity. Hinduism however, has eternal *kaal-chakra* (cyclic time), thus except the Supreme (Brahman) everything is temporary and subject to periodic creation (srishti) and dissolution (pralaya). Thus Hindu hell and heaven are not a permanent state of existence.

Comment: @Vivikta Thank you. Could you please then elaborate the role of heaven and hell in Hinduism? Please consider writing it as an answer, so that I can accept it!  Thanks.

Comment: For the Abhrahmic part, I don't have references. And it might be problematic if I cite them here, even if I find them.

Comment: @Vivikta could you then just write about the role of heaven and hell in Hinduism then?

Comment: That answer is already present on the site

Comment: The closest thing to Hell is Naraka. "Heaven" is basically the vast and diverse realms of the Deva.